# What is the side length of smallest square which can embed a regular polygon with 2*n sides, where n is odd and n≥3.

Tags: geometry, polygons, programming

I am trying to solve [problem](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1354/C2). I have proved that the minimum side length should be greater than or equal to radius of the circum circle of given regular polygon(by contradiction). 
But I am not able to find what is the tight lower bound for it. I am curious to know if some formula can be formed for this problem or is it neccessary to use programming constructs like loops. 
Please share your approaches for this.

Comment: Do you mean the minimum side should be less than twice the circumradius?  A circle with radius half the side fits in the square and a polygon fits inside the circle.

Comment: May be you could start by proving that the smallest square to be drawn around the odd polygon has one side of the polygon aligned with one side of the square.

Comment: @RossMillikan for n = 3 means for a hexagon the minimum side length is 1.931851653
 but the circum radius comes out to be 1 and hence diameter to be 2

Comment: @Moti can you please share what's the intution behind taking one side of polygon coinciding with the square even though the figure is symmetrical.

Comment: Yes, I see that.  In your question you said the minimum side length should be the circumradius.  I wanted to know if you thought that was $1$ or $2$.  The simple statement is the minimum side length is less than twice the circumradius because the circle will fit in the square.

Comment: @RossMillikan In my question I said that I proved minimum side length should be atleast  circumradius but I am not sure if square with side equal to circumradius will be sufficent to contain the polygon.

Comment: The factor $2$ comes because the side of the square is like the diameter of a circle, so if you know the circumradius of the polygon you need to double it for the side of the square.  It is guaranteed that if you double it, it will fit, because the whole circle will fit.  It is generally true that the minimum side of the square is a little less than double the circumradius.  Double the circumradius corresponds to putting opposite corners of the polygon on the sides of the square.  The flat sides will not touch the other two sides, so rotating the polygon will let you shrink the square.

Comment: I got your point. but I am looking for tight bound.

Comment: The intuition is You could draw a square around the polygon. This is a bound since by rotating the polygon 90 degrees you go through a need to enlarge the square or reduce it - it will linearly grow or decrease the square where the extreme will be at 45 degrees. I did not try it by I feel  that a small rotation of the polygon will cause the square to be a little larger. Compare the two cases - an aligned side to the 45 degrees rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N = 2n$ where $n \ge 3$ is odd.

Let's say we have a regular $N$-gon with circumradius $R = 1$ which fit inside  a square of side $s$. Choose a coordinate system where the circumcenter is origin and the sides of square are parallel to the coordinate axes. Reflect everything upside down if needed, one can find a $\theta \in [ 0, \frac{\pi}{N} ]$ so that one of the vertex of the $N$-gon is located at $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$.

In terms of  $\theta$, the vertices of the $N$-gon will be located at
$(\cos\theta_k,\sin\theta_k)$ where  $\theta_k = \theta + \frac{2\pi k}{N}$ for 
$k = 0,\ldots, N - 1$. In order for the $N$-gon to fit inside a square of side $s$. The shadow when we project the $N$-gon to $x$- and $y$- axes will have width $\le s$.

It is clear the width of the shadow on $x$-axis is $2\cos\theta$.

The shadow on $y$-axis
is $[-\sin\theta_k,\sin\theta_k]$ for $k = \lfloor \frac{N}{4}\rfloor = \frac{n-1}{2}$. This leads to

$$s \ge 2 \max\left( \cos\theta, \sin\left(\theta  + \frac{\pi(n-1)}{2n}\right)\right) = 2\max\left(\cos\theta, \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2n}-\theta\right)\right)$$
The minimum on RHS is achieved when $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2n} - \theta \iff \theta = \frac{\pi}{4n}$. This leads to
$$s \ge 2\cos\frac{\pi}{4n}$$

At $\theta =\frac{\pi}{4n}$, it is easy to see how to fit the $N$-gon
into an axes-aligned square of side $2\cos\frac{\pi}{4n}$. From this, we
can deduce:

> The smallest square which contains a regular $N$-gon with circumradius $R$ has side $2R\cos\frac{\pi}{4n}$.

As an example, for $n = 3$, we can fit a hexagon with unit circumradius into 
a square of $2\cos\frac{\pi}{12} \approx 1.931851652578137$

Comment: What if N is odd?

Comment: @martycohen If $N$ is odd, the width of the shadow is no longer $2 \times$ something. If I didn't make any mistake, it is $2\cos\frac{\pi}{2N}\cos\frac{\pi}{4N}$.

Comment: @achillehui  Thanks I got your approach Today I have seen some people  used this formula 1/(2*sin(pi/4n)) for the same problem. Do you think these formulae are related or one can be derived from other.

Comment: @NipulSindwani the formula you have is for a regular $2n$-gon with side $1$. For such $2n$-gon, $R = \frac{1}{2\sin(\pi/2n)} \implies s = \frac{\cos(\pi/4n)}{\sin(\pi/2n)} = \frac{1}{2\sin(\pi/4n)}$